# Problem with tkinter treeview -- tag_bind() function

Tags: tkinter, tags, treeview

I do have a problem with bindings in the treeview widget.

I made a while loop and binds there the functionality I want on the said treeview item with the following code:

```
self.tre.tag_bind(name,"<Double-1>", callback=lambda event, name=name: self.load_in_modules(name))
self.tre.tag_bind(name,"<Button-3>", callback=lambda event, name=name: self.load_in_submodules(name))
```

The bindings works like a charm but when I make a child of an item in the treeview and do the same kind of binding, nothing happens at all. I don't even get an error message. It's like there is no binding at all.

Any suggestions how to solve it?
-regards-

---

### EDIT

Putting the entire loop here (as i put it with norwegian words):

```
b = len(self.Data_moduler)
start = 0
while start < b:
    navn = self.Data_moduler[start]
    self.tre.insert("","end",iid=navn,text=navn,tags=navn)
    self.tre.tag_bind(navn,"<Double-1>", callback=lambda event, navn=navn:self.laste_inn_moduler(navn))
    self.tre.tag_bind(navn,"<Button-3>", callback=lambda event, navn=navn:self.legg_inn_undermoduler(navn))
    start += 1
```

that's the code for the while loop I use to populate the treeview. I use the same type of lamda when adding a child to a given item in the treeview:

```
hovedmodul = navn
undermodul = self.entry_50.get() #From a pop up window i've created
modul = hovedmodul + "." + undermodul
b = len(undermodul)
if b > 0:
    self.tre.insert(hovedmodul,"end",iid=modul, text=undermodul)
    self.tre.tag_bind(modul, "<Button-3>", callback=lambda event, modul=modul: self.laste_inn_moduler(modul))
```

Comment: Please include the `while` loop in the example by creating a complete [mcve]. If you're doing the same bind for each iteration of the loop, only the last one will be the one that works.

Comment: Hello Bryan. Have updated the code I did